# remove the directory path from the first column using awk

Tags: awk

I have a data file whose columns are of interest to me, which i am taking out by awk as shown below. I want to get rid of the directory path coming in $1 in the same awk command. Is it possible?

```
cat data.txt | awk '{print $1,$2,$6,$7,$14,$15,$16}'

 /foo1/foo2/debug/foo.txt:06/28 10:44:44.066 delta 1:1: net transfer 1263
 /foo1/foo2/debug/foo1.txt:06/29 10:45:48.066 delta 2:1: net transfer 1296

   after transformation the row should be like...

 foo.txt:06/28 10:44:44.066 delta 1:1: net transfer 1263
 foo1.txt:06/29 10:45:48.066 delta 2:1: net transfer 1296
```

Comment: Can any of your file or directory names contain `:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove using `sub` with a regular expression:

```
awk '{sub("/[^:]*/","",$1); print $1,$2,$6,$7,$14,$15,$16}' data.txt
```

(As pointed out in the question's comments, this regex assumes that your file and directory names will not contain `:`)